# Is there any way to select everything that is not currently selected?

Tags: modeling

I want to be able to select certain vertices, apply a texture, and then select the rest to apply another texture. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> inverts your selection.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to add many textures to one object that has several faces:

- cycles render
- material tab click "use nodes"
- texture tab click "new"
- click open find texture you wish to use
- click material tab look for surface menu
- then to the right of color click the little box icon
  Color: ______[]<----
- choose image texture
- an up/down arrow appears
- choose the texture
- go into edit mode and face select, then enable texture mode
- click on the first face and hold shift and highlight each additional area
- now press "U" on the keyboard and choose "unwrap"
- then go to materials tab and click "assign"
- now just add more textures and assign to each face

Comment: This is a nice description of adding a texture and viewing it but doesn't consider the main question **Is there any way to *select* everything that is not currently selected?** which focuses on selecting and inverting a selection.